# MySQL Query where id = id_product error

Tags: mysql

i'm working with mysql in a nodejs web app. I don't understand why when I ask for some `id` (key) it gives me more than 1 result.

When I:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 1;
```

This happens, I get **3 results**, but I only want 1:
`1`, `001` and `0000001`.
I just want the info of one product (`id: 1` in this example)

How can I fix this?
ID type is **varchar(20)**

If I use `LIKE` instead of `=` my result changes:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id LIKE 0000001;
```

I get the info of id = `1` instead `0000001`. Don't know why.

Thanks

Comment: What data type is your `id` column?

Comment: My answer has already been pasted below in a similar form by another user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking by a varchar type using an integer cast.

Try to add quotes to the id parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1';
```

If you want to add integer ids with with leading zeros, I recommend you to use the zerofill option:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

If you want to use use alphanumeric values then keeps the ID type as varchar, but remember to enclose the search param into quotes.

Comment: You are right. It's an old project I got to improve it. And Im not familiarized with the code and DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause of your query contains a comparison of a literal numeric value with a string (column `id`).

When it needs to compare values of different type, MySQL uses several rules to convert one or both of the values to a common type.

Some of the [type conversion rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) are not intuitive. The last rule is the only one that matches a comparison of an integer number with a string:

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

When they are converted to floating-point (real) numbers, `1` (integer), `'1'`, `'0001'` and `'0000001'` are all equal.

In order to get an exact match the literal value you put in the query must have the same type as the column `id` (i.e string). The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '1'
```

Comment: I got it now. Explained very well.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in MySQL (and the real world) don't have leading zeros.  Strings do.

So, you just need to make the comparison using the right type:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id = '1';
```

What happens with your original query is that the `id` is converted to a number.  And `'1'`, `'001'` and '`0000001'` are all converted to the same integer -- `1`.  Hence, all three pass the filter.

Comment: Data type of id is varchar. So it doesn't works. So any way to fix it? Or it's a bad implementation?

Comment: @Baumann . . . Fix what?  This seems to answer your question.  If you want another value, then use that -- as a string:  `'0001'`.